# what's the point of having a jquery-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I installed Ruby on Rails(first time) and got down to starting a new project and a server. So as expected there was an error on running the Rails server command. Some gems needed to be installed, apparently. The bundle install command didn't work for some wierd ssl issue. So I decided to do it all 
manually.

What strikes me as odd is that there's a gem for jQuery: jquery-rails. I don't understand the point of this, really. Why not simply download the jquery file and put it in public.
What's the point of having a gem here. 
Is it simply convinience or is there another important reason behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery-rails does 2 things. First of all it bundles the appropriate version of jquery. I consider this only a convenience for jquery itself. For something like jquery-ui, jquery-ui-rails does a lot more: since jquery-ui is modular, that gem will serve to clients only the bits of jquery-ui you are using.

The other thing in jquery-rails is jquery-ujs. This is javascript that makes things such as passing the :remote => true option to form_for work. It used to be that rails itself contained a version of this for prototype, but with rails 3 this was extracted from rails to make it easier to use other javascript libraries than rails' previous default of prototype

Comment: Okay so it is a convinience after all. Jquery UI could be convinient. I admit I never got over the get it from the repository and put it there technique. I distrust any system that does too much of the work by itself. Composer is another thing I never got in the habbit of liking. Maybe someday

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good idea, because it makes JQuery available as a versioned dependency.

If you need to update JQuery, you just have to change the version at one place in your app, and every page that needs it will use the new version.

And based on its [homepage](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails), there's also a test helper that you can use in your tests.